# What does “aber” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-particle

What does “aber” mean in English in the following sentence?

> Das habe ich aber nicht bestellt.
>
> That's not what I ordered.

Comment: Clearly a duplicate; unfortunately, the answers on the other question are as incorrect as on this one.

Comment: @chirlu: Ich hatte mich geirrt. 'Aber' wird hier wohl tatsächlich als Konjunktion oder Konnektor-Adverb eingeordnet, nicht als Abtönungspartikel. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aber_Konjunktion_Bedeutung_doch Auch könnte es im Vorfeld / vor dem finiten Verb stehen, was Abtönungspartikeln nicht könnten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken out of context, the "aber" has no meaning at all. The literal translation of

> That's not what I ordered.

is

> Das habe ich nicht bestellt

"Aber" is a conjunction or a modal particle (and in this case a modal particle), it combines what was previous said with the sentence at hand. In english, its best expressed using "but", e.g. in

> "Here is your X" - "But thats not what I ordered."

So, in this case, the sentence means

> But that is not what I ordered.

It refences what was said (or offered) just before.

Comment: While there is a conjunction _aber_, that’s obviously not the word in this sentence; there are no two clauses a conjunction could connect. This _aber_ is a modal particle.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate "aber" in this context as "however," even though it usually means "but."

> "Das habe ich aber nicht bestellt.
>
> That's not what I ordered," *however*.

Comment: This answer also fails to correctly identify _aber_ as a modal particle. _Duden_ [describes it](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aber_Partikel) as expressing emphasis and/or emotional involvement of the speaker.